# "warning: RTTI symbol not found for class" with intel compiler

Tags: gdb, rtti, icc

I am seeing these GDB warnings when I complied the below code with intel compiler 14.
I am using eclipse Kepler in RHEL6.5.

Code: (example from cplusplus.com)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main () {

  std::shared_ptr<int> foo = std::make_shared<int> (10);
  // same as:
  std::shared_ptr<int> foo2 (new int(10));

  auto bar = std::make_shared<int> (20);

  auto baz = std::make_shared<std::pair<int,int>> (30,40);

  std::cout << "*foo: " << *foo << '\n';
  std::cout << "*bar: " << *bar << '\n';
  std::cout << "*baz: " << baz->first << ' ' << baz->second << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

GDB Warning:

```
warning: RTTI symbol not found for class 'std::num_get<wchar_t, std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> > >'
warning: RTTI symbol not found for class 'std::num_get<wchar_t, std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> > >'
warning: RTTI symbol not found for class 'std::num_get<wchar_t, std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> > >'
```

Build:
    make -k all 
    Building file: ../src/test2.cpp
    Invoking: Intel Intel(R) 64 C++ Compiler 
    icpc -g -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF"src/test2.d" -MT"src/test2.d" -c -o "src/test2.o" "../src/test2.cpp"

I don't see these warnings with g++ 4.72. Any issue with this warning? Thanks.